# Can the meaning of "cost" correctly be used to refer to "time" here?

Tags: word-choice

In the following construction, can I use *costed* to mean *consumed*?

> Working through these steps *cost* much time, but it was worthwhile to get a good outcome.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't really understand your question. Can you give us a little more context, or perhaps make it more clear what you're asking so we can give you a good answer? I don't see the word 'consumed' anywhere else in the sentence, so 'costed' can't refer to it; therefore I'm not really sure what you mean. I will say this: in your second sentence, it should say *cost*, not *costed*.

Comment: Also see wiktionary's usage note for *[costed](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/costed#Verb)*:  «The only non-proscribed use is in the sense of “to give a cost to”. Where proper grammar is expected, use cost instead for non-specialized past-tense and past-participle uses such as answering the question “How much did it cost?”»

Comment: @jwpat7: That's now *three* of us who've all posted links to different sites making the same point about "costed". The grammar obviously bothers us at least as much as OP's actual question (is the *meaning* okay?).

Comment: I think the question is probably NARQ because it is asking the meaning of a word in a sentence that doesn't fit grammatically. We can all try and guess what the author intended, or say what the word costed means in the general case, but when the grammar of the sentence is wrong we can't do better than that. If the OP is the author, the question should be rephrased into something answerable. Otherwise the question is probably NARQ.

Comment: @Matt♦: I think that's *way* OTT. Like most questioners, the OP has limited command of the niceties of English tense, etc. But it's quite clear to me he's only asking whether it's valid to say something ***cost** much/a lot of **time*** on *semantic* grounds. It's quite obvious what the sentence is *intended* to mean, given the second clause after the comma. It's also obvious exactly what he's asking about, given both the title itself, and the (admittedly ungrammatical) final line in the question text. I'll edit to head off the overenthusiastic downvoters.

Comment: @Matt♦: I was editing the question text as you closed it. Please reopen to save me the trouble of raising this on meta.

Comment: @FumbleFingers In all fairness, the original question wasn't very readable before your edit. It makes much more sense now, however, so I've gone ahead and reopened it. Thanks for greatly improving the post!

Comment: @WendiKidd, Matt: I'm sure I'm as "close-vote happy" as anyone here on ELL, but I'm surprised at the close/downvotes for this question. If someone could convince me that the *time is money* metaphor isn't well understood in *all* languages, there might have been a case for closing as General Reference (except that reason doesn't exist on ELL). But to downrate a question just because a non-native speaker doesn't frame it in good English seems extreme to me. And I really don't see that the original text was particularly hard to understand, or that the question itself was vague. It was specific.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The *meaning* is perfectly okay - it's an example of the extremely common [Time is Money](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/TIM.pdf) metaphor...

> [I **spent** the afternoon [doing such-and-such]](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22I%20spent%20the%20afternoon%22&oq=%22I%20spent%20the%20afternoon%22&gs_l=serp.3...10403898.10414756.1.10415076.51.44.1.0.0.4.127.2170.43j1.44.0...0.0...1c.1.8.serp.2asCB9KKKtk&psj=1&biw=1396&bih=872&cad=cbv&sei=mdFlUcv2FMav0QXLpoAY)

The *grammar* is wrong though - it should be [**cost**, not **costed**](http://grammarist.com/usage/costed/)...

> When the verb **cost** means *to be priced at* or *to cause loss or expenditure*, it is uninflected in the past tense and as a past participle.

What that's saying is *to cost* is an [Irregular Verb](http://www.usingenglish.com/reference/irregular-verbs/cost.html). The uninflected form *(cost)* is used for past as well as present tense in all except *one specific case*. The "regular, inflected" past tense form **costed** is only (and always) used when the verb has the modern sense of *quantified/calculated the cost of [something]*.

It's "worth" pointing out that although he obviously didn't realise it, OP's own **worthwhile** reflects exactly the same metaphoric usage (*worth = has the **value** of*, and *while* references the duration of time **spent**). OP's alternative *consumed* is a completely different metaphor based on *eaten = taken [in] = used up*.

---

Not specifically part of OP's question, but this usage of *much time* wouldn't sound very natural to most Anglophones today (it's a bit archaic). We'd more likely say something like ***a lot of*** time, or ***many*** days.

Comment: Surely you are right, but, only for the register, I noticed that CGE says: "when *cost* means 'estimate the monetary costs of doing or producing (something),' its past tense has the regular *-ed* inflection".

Comment: @Carlo_R.: Perhaps you can rephrase that (I don't see what you mean). It seems to me your CGE citation is saying exactly the same thing as my own quote from [grammarist.com](http://grammarist.com/). What is "only for the register"?

Comment: Sorry FF, I was under the wrong impression that CGE says something different from grammarist.com. If you do not understand "only for the register", it is sure it is not idiomatic English. In fact it is a phrase I translated word-by-word from Italian just to say "just to say something that is not important".

Comment: @Carlo_R.: The standard way of putting that in English would be *in passing*, or *by the way* (or my idiomatic favourite, *by the by*). But I'll edit my answer to clarify - if even you misunderstood, I'm sure many other non-native speakers won't get it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: thank you for the good clarification

Comment: @gnp: I'd be interested to know if your own native language normally uses "time is money" metaphors, and how you understood the meaning of *worthwhile* which you seem to have used quite naturally and correctly in your example. Note that *worthwhile* is effectively a contraction of *worth the while*, meaning *having equal/greater **value** than the **amount of time** required to do it*.

Comment: I’ve also seen cost being used not to refer to either time or money.  E.g. Article: The cost of human error. ‘In medicine, these mistakes can cost a life.’

Comment: @EnglishLearner: Exactly. One of the most famous such usages being the UK govt's WW2 [Careless talk costs lives](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22careless+talk+costs+lives%22+ww2&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=mj9oUbrjA-mA0AWZl4GgAw&ved=0CDcQsAQ&biw=1396&bih=872) campaign. But note that "cost" was never exclusively applied in monetary contexts. OED's current definition starts with *That which must be given or surrendered in order to acquire, produce, accomplish, or maintain something* - you don't always have to have money to pay a cost.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand your phrase, I would say:

> Working with these steps **took a lot of** time, but they were worthwhile to get a good outcome.

*took* (past tense of *take*) refers to what occurred over a period of time. For example:

> It **took** 3 hours to get into the theater.
>
> It **takes** several days to receive the package.

In your phrase, I prefer *a lot of* instead of *much*, but I can't say if *much* is incorrect or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either *cost* or *consumed*, but I don't think they mean quite the same thing.

*Consumed* simply means something took a lot of time. My wife is an artisan, and some of her crafts are very *time-consuming*, in that they take days (if not weeks) to complete.

In your sentence, however, *cost* implies that not only did it take a lot of time, but that time was detrimental somehow. It could mean that workers were being paid (so it cost a lot of money), or it could mean that a project fell behind schedule (so we lost some time in our planned schedule).

So, if you want to imply that the extra time was worth some cost, *cost* is the better word to used. But if you only want to infer that the activity was painstaking and time-consuming, then *consumed* might be the better word.

Comment: I think that *cost/consumed* distinction is a post-hoc rationalisation. Fire "consumes" things - come to that, [consumption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuberculosis) (TB) is pretty dire. And in any real-world context I can imagine, the actual use of the less-common "consumed" in OP's context would be in order to explain the very bad consequence of having fallen well behind schedule. In that context, *cost* could be neutral accounting terminology for a simple statement of fact, not an inquest into failings.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Maybe I should have stated this explicitly: when I was "defining" _cost_ vs. _consume_ here, my scope was limited solely to the O.P.'s context; i.e., "cost time" vs. "consume time." You are right to point out that both words have meanings that go beyond those contexts, so this should not be taken as a defining answer for all situations.

Comment: Yeah - I don't disagree with the basic principle that each different metaphoric reference works in a different way. Actually, the question text (which was pretty dire in the original form, as I'm sure you know) has now been changed *again* in a way that emphasises OP's use of the alternative *consumed*. I think to some extent the TIME IS FOOD metaphor is actually a subset of TIME IS MONEY as per my link to John Lawler's piece on the subject *(money = valuable/fundamental resource = food)*, but I prolly ought to edit my answer to address that usage too.